# How DO I change the street view result after searching using places API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-street-view

I'm trying to change my split view streetview/maps screen to the result of a search in a places text field.  The maps changes to the location, but I have been unable to get the street view to change tot he same address/location.  Any help is appreciated.

what I've done is as follows and it's not working:

```
if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);

        var newpano = map.getStreetView();
        newpano.setPano(place.location.pano);
        newpano.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Places API does not provide Street View panos, there is no `place.location.pano`

You can use send [Street View Service Requests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewService) from JavaScript, to find the nearest pano to the `place.geometry.location` (latlng), and pass that on to `setPano()`

You may also be interested in: [Issue 6033: Feature Request: Business Tour](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6033)

Comment: Thanks @miguev.  I appreciate the direction.